# Is my console.log() supposed run 3 times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Below is the code for one of my Components pages. It's to enter some ticket data into a MongoDB database.  I'm trying to get the customer information to self populate by selecting a customer name in the dropdown box.  I put a console.log() on line 18 just to see if I could figure out at what point the data from the customer collection is set.  It appears when I have the console.log() on line 18 it runs through like 3 times.  The first two times it's logging an empty array, but the 3rd time it has the data from MongoDB.  I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm a little confused why that console.log is getting ran 3 times.  I'm a little shy about posting my code because I'm still so know that I'm sure I'm doing all sorts of stuff wrong, but can someone stear me in the right direction on this?  Is it supposed to be running multiple times?  Also, I'm getting the following warning that I'm having trouble figuring out:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
Check the render method of `Tickets`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more information.
    in Fragment (created by Tickets)
    in Tickets (at App.js:22)
    in Route (at App.js:21)
    in Switch (at App.js:20)
    in div (at App.js:18)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:17)
    in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

I know it has something to do with my dropdown selection at line 97, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happy.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DeleteBtn from "../DeleteBtn";
import Jumbotron from "../Jumbotron";
import API from "../../utils/API";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row, Container } from "../Grid";
import { List, ListItem } from "../List";
import { Input, FormBtn } from "../Form";

const moment = require('moment');

function Tickets(props) {
  // Setting our component's initial state
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState([])
  const [formObject, setFormObject] = useState({})
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([])

  console.log("Customer = ", customers)

  // Load all tickets and store them with setTickets
  useEffect(() => {
    loadTickets()
  }, [])

  // Loads all tickets and sets them to tickets
  function loadTickets() {
    API.getTickets()
      .then(res => 
        setTickets(res.data)
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };  

  // Load all Customers and store them with setCustomer
  useEffect(() => {
    loadCustomers()
  }, [])

  // Loads all customers and sets them to customers
  function loadCustomers() {
    API.getCustomers()
    .then(res =>
      setCustomers(res.data)
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  // Deletes a ticket from the database with a given id, then reloads tickets from the db
  function deleteTicket(id) {
    API.deleteTicket(id)
      .then(res => loadTickets())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

 // Handles updating component state when the user types into the input field
 function handleInputChange(event) {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setFormObject({...formObject, [name]: value})
 };

 // When the form is submitted, use the API.saveTicket method to save the ticket data
// Then reload tickets from the database
  function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (formObject.ticketDate) {
      API.saveTicket({
        ticketDate: formObject.ticketDate,
        ticketNum: formObject.ticketNum,
        ticketCust: formObject.ticketCust,
        ticketCustStreet: formObject.ticketCustStreet
      })
        .then(res => loadTickets())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        document.getElementById("ticketFrm").reset();  
        setFormObject({})      
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col size="md-6">
          <Jumbotron>
            <h1>Add Ticket</h1>
          </Jumbotron>
          <form id="ticketFrm">
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketDate"
              placeholder="Date"
            />
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketNum"
              placeholder="Ticket Number (required)"
            />          
            <select onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCust"
              placeholder= "Customer Name"
              style={{width: '100%', height: 35, marginBottom: 15}}>
              {customers.map(customers => (
               <> 
               <option value="" hidden>Select Customer</option>
               <option default="Customer" key={customers._id}>{customers.custName}</option>  
              </>   
              ))}
            </select>
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCustStreet"
              placeholder="Street"
            /> 
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCustCity"
              placeholder="City"
            /> 
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCustState"
              placeholder="State"
            /> 
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCustZip"
              placeholder="Zip"
            /> 
            <Input
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              name="ticketCustMaterial"
              placeholder="Material"
            /> 
            <FormBtn
              disabled={!(formObject.ticketNum)}
              onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
              Submit Ticket
            </FormBtn>
          </form>
        </Col>
        <Col size="md-6 sm-12">
            <Jumbotron>
              <h1>Current Tickets</h1>
            </Jumbotron>
            {tickets.length ? (
              <List>
                {tickets.map(tickets => (
                  <ListItem key={tickets._id}>
                    <Link to={"/Tickets/" + tickets._id}>
                      <strong>
                      Ticket Date - {moment(tickets.ticketDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
                        <br></br>
                      Ticket# - {tickets.ticketNum}
                      <br></br>
                      {tickets.ticketCust}
                      </strong>
                    </Link>
                    <DeleteBtn onClick={() => deleteTicket(tickets._id)}/>
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
            ) : (
              <h3>No Results to Display</h3>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
}

export default Tickets;
```

Thanks for any input, and please don't judge me too hard on my code.

Thanks,

-N8

Answer (score 2):

First, it's ok to be new to something, and i don't think you should apologise.
best way to learn is by asking questions, do mistakes and get you hands 'dirty', so feel free :).

regarding the keys issue, basically each element you are rendering from an array need to have a unique key so react would know when change occurs on specific elements.
so there is a chance some your data holds same `_id` some how.
for example you can pass the index of the current element on the iteration (just add the index argument to map function) but i wont use it for your case as your list changes and it's an anti-pattern.
for more info about keys please read the next:
[React keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
[index as keys anti pattern](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/)

regarding the console.log that occurs more then once:
it's ok as the `render` will run every time there is a change on you component state.
so at the beginning you are starting with empty array(s), and when there is a change on any of your state's the function will run and prints the console log.
there is a nice guide i found on react rendering, you can dive into:
[Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)

hope you'll find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` hooks are being called after the component is mounted to the DOM. The first console logs are being called with undefined data (as the call has not been made yet)

With regards to `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys. When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

So to remove your warning I would do something like

```
{customers.map((customers, ii) => (
               <> 
               <option value="" key={ii} hidden>Select Customer</option>
               <option default="Customer" key={customers._id}>{customers.custName}</option>  
              </>   
              ))}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Feedback.  I'm still having a little trouble with this.  I've changed my code to to exactly what you have listed there, But I'm still getting the same warning.  I've read the docs about KEYS, but I think what's throwing me off is the fact I have the <select> and <option> tags instead of <ul> and <li> tags.  Any thoughts?